# Finding second derivative of a function with a square root

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find inflection points and local maximum and minimum of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x-2}}$. Domain of the function is $(-\infty, 0] \cup (2, +\infty) $. I have found the first derivative: $f'(x)=\frac{x^2(x-3)}{(x-2)^2}\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x^3}} $ and local minimum $ x =3$.

I first tried to simplify this to find the second derivative.
$f'(x)=\frac{x^2(x-3)}{(x-2)^2}\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x^3}} = 
(x-3)\sqrt{\frac{x^4(x-2)}{x^3(x-2)^4}} = 
(x-3)\sqrt{\frac{x}{(x-2)^3} }  $

Is this correct?

And how can I obtain $f''(x)=\frac{3x}{(x-2)^3\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x -2}}} $ (found using Wolfram Mathematica). I have tried, but I can't get this simple form and I can't find the inflection points. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find the second derivative to see that $f(3)=3\sqrt3$ is a local minimum point:
$$f'(x)=(x-3)\sqrt{\frac{x}{(x-2)^3} }\\
x=3-\varepsilon \Rightarrow f'(x)<0,x=3+\varepsilon \Rightarrow f'(x)>0$$
In fact, there are two critical points:
$$f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x_1=0,x_2=3$$
Note that $f(0)=0$ is a global minimum, since $f(x)\ge 0$.

So, there are no inflection points as you claim. See Desmos [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lco3fijpq7).